# Problems with import in Ionic Native Plugins in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have two problems:

*Problem nr1:*

**app.module.ts**

```
// Native plugins
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { PhotoViewer } from '@ionic-native/photo-viewer/ngx';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';

...

  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    ...guards,
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    PhotoViewer,
    Camera,
    File,
    FileTransfer,
  ],
```

[image]

So, the `providers` gets underlined once I provide any of the native plugins.
If I will not provide any of NativePlugins, (comment all lines, starting from `StatusBar,`) - then the `providers` doesn't get underlined with that red curve.

*Problem nr2:*

**some component state.ts**

[image]

In any component, when I try to use the native plugins, I get this error.
This error does not reflect on `app.moduls.ts` providers array.
I can provide or not provide the Native Plugins in `app.moduls.ts` - the error is still shown.

All native plugins, like you see, are imported from `@ionic-native/.../ngx`. So the path is correct, because I read similar posts, and the problem was that the path did not end up with `/ngx`, or the plugins where not provided in `app.module.ts`. But this is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have figured out the problem.
It seems to be VS Code bug.
There is not bug in the code itself.

The root problem was that I hade two more projects with node_modules directory added in this project in the root directory,
like in root directory there is my project with `node_modules` directory, and
two more projects with similar structure:

```
/project1/...
/project1/node_modules
/project2/...
/project2/node_modules
```

I used these projects to take some code/components from them.

I think that the VS Code was looking in a wrong `node_modules` directory, thus the it take wrong plugin versions and hence the error message was displayed.

Now I moved these two projects out of my project - and there is no more errors.